# Mysql function DATE() on sql server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, function

I need to convert this MYSQL query to sql server:

DATE(datetime_field);

How can i translate this query on sql server language?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/en-en/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: you know that stackoverflow is not a writting Service or? at least mark the answer when you got it.

Comment: @TabAlleman, i have searched on google but i searched the wrong way indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either of the following ..

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,datetime_field)
```

OR

```
 SELECT CAST (datetime_field as date)
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the following:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL server 2008 or above, try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select try_convert(date, datetimefield)
```

or

```
select try_cast(datetimefield as date)
```

If you get invalid date it will not error out instead it will return null

Answer (score 0):

**CONVERT** also has an handy 3rd argument which allows to format the date using some predefined styles (returns varchar)

so for example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112)
```

will output today's daye in ISO format like 20160831

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103)
```

would output 31/08/2016

...and so on...

see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Select Convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),103) AS CurrentDate